# Stove wire harness connector burnt

Tags: stove, range

Samsung stove Ne58f9710ws.
Front right heating element always high even when set to low and doesn't cycle on and off (stays on).

Initially replaced the infinite switch and it worked for a few months but issue occurred again.

Wire harness connector is pretty burnt.
Are these standard connectors?

Anyone know of any options to splice and replace the connector?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Looks like standard spade connetors in some sort of molex enclosure. You can probably just crimp or solder on a spade connector and fix the immediate problem, but that doesn't explain why the thing burnt in the first place.

Comment: Probably need to check/replace that blue box/cover also.  Heat probably did more damage than just the connector.

Comment: Thanks. Is it okay to remove the insulation from a regular female spade as I cannot find the "high temp" non-insulated spades locally. The original damage was to the replaced infinite switch and I replaced it with a new one a few months ago. Not sure if this new one is now also damaged or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely reason for that melting is that the original crimp connector did not make good contact with the spade lug, causing a high-resistance path for the current.

Replacing the crimped connector *might* be all that's needed, if the heating control is not damaged.

- Be sure the crimp connector is rated for the high temperature in a stove.
- Be sure the crimp connector is rated for the high current (at least 20 or 30 amps) drawn by the heating element.
- Be sure the crimp connector is rated for wire size, perhaps 14 gauge (1.6 mm) or 12 gauge (2 mm).
- Strip the wire back to where the copper conductor is shiny.
- Crimp the connector tightly.
- Be sure to push connector so that the spade lug goes *inside* the connector. It appears, in the photo, that the spade lug might have been placed between the outside of the connector and the inside of the plastic insulator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sounds like you're right. When I initialled replaced the infinite switch I should have replaced the burnt connector as well. I'll replace the connector first to see if it's working and if not, I guess I'll have to replace the switch again.